# Mysql max not working

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably a question that can be answered in one line but literally i HAVEN'T been able to find it in two hours.

```
<?php 

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
if(!$con){
  die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
}
@mysql_select_db("uni",$con) or die("Unable to select db");

$query  = "SELECT MAX(grade) AS HighestPrice from grades";
$res  = mysql_query($query);
if(!$res){
   echo mysql_error();
   exit;
}
else{

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo "The max num is ". $row['HighestPrice']."this is it";
}
}
```

What i want it to return is the max of grades table USING max command. Just to mention that the whole sql command that i do want to make needs to have min also, so if possible to add that too it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's not working? What happens? Errors? What does your output look like in your sql tools? And oh, don't use mysql_*. Why? A simple search will tell you.

Comment: "Not working". Why doesn't it work? Do you get an error? Does MySQL crash? Does your server crash? Does it start downloading spam? Making weird noises? Does it catch on fire? This post is similar to me posting a picture of my car and asking "it won't work".

Comment: order on grade descending and take the first item.

Comment: No, it is just not returning the right value..

Comment: What column-type is "grade"? `INT`?

Comment: @Dreamwalker, i just want to do it jusing max and min it is crazy not being possible..

Comment: @user2581671 You can't just expect us to know what it's returning right now.

Comment: @h2ooooooo literally thanks was varchar...... terribly sorry to all for you time. Make it an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @Dreamwalker Shouldn't be required since max should only be returning a single result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column type was `VARCHAR`, and therefore a string - not an integer. These are treated differently when using `MAX()`.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max):

> Returns the maximum value of expr. **`MAX()` may take a string argument; in such cases, it returns the maximum string value.** See Section 8.5.1, “How MySQL Uses Indexes”. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to find the maximum of the distinct values of expr, however, this produces the same result as omitting DISTINCT.

To fix this, simply convert your column into a `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `INT`, `BIGINT` or `DECIMAL` based on your needs.

If you'll always have a whole number with no decimals, use one of the `INT` types (whatever matches your needs the best).

Here's a table from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) so you can pick the right type for your column:

[image]